# Rails: Error when creating devise session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

In my application I am trying to manually make devise sessions unusable by setting a `session_validity_token`.

**How I do it:**

- The devise User model has a column named `session_validity_token`
- I also have a SeesionHistory model which has the same column

In my devise initialization ...

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user except: :fetch do |user, warden, opts|
  user.update_attribute(:session_validity_token, Devise.friendly_token) if user.session_validity_token.nil?
  warden.raw_session["validity_token"] = user.session_validity_token
end

Warden::Manager.after_fetch do |user, warden, opts|
  unless user.session_histories.unblocked.where(session_validity_token: warden.raw_session["validity_token"]).exists?
    warden.logout
  end
end
```

... when a user signs in or up I set the `validity_token` of the stored Cookie to the Users `session_validity_token`. If the User doesn't have one yet (signup), I create a token.
... when a URL gets fetched I check before authorizing the User if a unblocked session to that token exists. If not, the User gets logged out.

In the ApplicationController ...

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    session = SessionHistory.create(user_id: current_user.id, session_validity_token: current_user.session_validity_token)
    current_user.update_attribute(:session_validity_token, Devise.friendly_token)

    request.env['omniauth.origin'] || stored_location_for(resource) || root_path
end
```

... after a User gets signed in, I create a SessionHistory Record and simply set it's `session_validity_token` to the Users token and then recreate the Users token.

Unfortunately I get the following error:

> NoMethodError in Users::SessionsController#create
>   undefined method `session_validity_token' for nil:NilClass

Here is the SessionController#Create Action:

```
def create
    if User.where("email = '#{params[:user][:login]}' or username = '#{params[:user][:login]}'").exists?
        @user = User.find(User.where("email = '#{params[:user][:login]}' or username = '#{params[:user][:login]}'").first.id)
        if @user.confirmed? || ((Time.now - @user.created_at).to_i / (24 * 60 * 60)) < 1
            super
        else
            redirect_to new_user_confirmation_path(q: "unconfirmed")
        end
    else
        flash[:alert] = "The email or username does not match any accounts"
        redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
end
```

So I guess I did something wrong when handling the tokens with Warden ...

Please ask if you need additional Information.

Comment: I am not an expert in use of `devise`, but I cannot find a column named `session_validity_token` in any of my apps or the `devise` source, so I am wondering if what you have is a namespace collision with two customizations for `session_validity_token`?  Do you have the option of renaming the symbol in your `SessionHistory` model?

Comment: Thank you for that good point! I think that's the problem indeed. I changed the column name to something abstract and it seems to work fine, although I'm still testing it. You can write up an answer to close this question. Thank you again! I would have invested countless hours to find what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a namespace collision between two customizations named `session_validity_token`.  This is not naturally in the `Devise` model (and is not in the source for `devise`--I checked that).

If that is the case, and you have power over the source, consider changing the name of one, or both of the `session_validity_token` symbols to clarify the specific usage and relieve the conflict.

Comment: Would love if some day devise would come natively with session history and session blocking :)